# An strange error happened with Arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Today I encountered a strange error. It took me lots of time.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("list people size:");
            System.out.println(listPeople.size());


            listPeople.clear();
            ArrayList<PeopleModel> newList = new ArrayList<PeopleModel>();
            newList = smsUtils.getPeopleList();
            // newList.size() = 42.
            for(int i=0;i<newList.size();i++){ 
                System.out.println(i);
                listPeople.add(newList.get(i));
            }
            //**strange error happened in loop above. I don't know why**
            // **it loops to infinity and causes outofmemory.**
            System.out.println("list new people size:");
            System.out.println(newList.size());

            if(adapter!=null){

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Previously, I used :

```
listPeople = smsUtils.getPeopleList();
```

But another strange error happened. `listPeople` now has 84 elements instead of 42.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `for (int i = 0, l = newList.size(); i < l; i++)`?
Also you can copy all elements of one array to another using `listPeople.addAll(newList)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ArrayList<PeopleModel> newList = new ArrayList<PeopleModel>();
newList = smsUtils.getPeopleList();
for(int i=0;i<newList.size();i++){ 
    System.out.println(i);
    listPeople.add(newList.get(i)); // Here's the infinity problem.
}
```

You're iterating from zero to the SIZE of newList. The problem is that at every loop you're ADDING to the newList. So... The size of newList grows up to infinity, and the loop never stops.

Comment: are you sure? newList.size()... listPeople.add

Comment: "newList = smsUtils.getPeopleList();" The "getPeopleList()" method must be returning the listPeople.

Comment: Yes. First he initialize the newList with a misterious list that comes from "smsUtils.getPeopleList()", then he iterates to the size of it (Which is supposed to be 42). Inside the loop he adds to listPeople what comes from newList. What comes from "newList.get(i)" must be from the listPeople itself, and since newList must be listPeople itself from the very beginning, the loop will never end.

Comment: @EricsonWillians , you're right, I made a serious and stupid mistake.
And the problem is solved ^^
Thank you and everybody very much.

Comment: I wonder this could have not happened using the for(PeopleModel person: newList) {}... because you can't change the collection with the foreach. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good reason to use the java foreach. You could have discovered the problem (that was you were using the same array reference for newList and listPeople) using the foreach statement instead of a for(int i=0;i<newList.size();i++).

Try this:

```
public class Train {
    public void doit() {
        List<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        newList.add(1);
        newList.add(2);
        newList.add(3);
        newList.add(4);
        newList.add(5);

        for(Integer elem: newList){
            System.out.println(newList.size());
            newList.add(6);
        }
        //instead of:
        /*for(int i=0;i<newList.size();i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            newList.add(6);
        }*/
    }

}
```

and you'll get at compile time:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.checkForComodification(AbstractList.java:372)
    at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:343)
    at my.webapp.utils.Train.doit(Train.java:26)
    at RunTrain.runDoit(RunTrain.java:9)
```